# How to write the cosets for given group?

Tags: group-theory

I am so sorry. Even i am understanding the definition of coset i am unable to write the cosets left and right.

I have a question.
WOuld anyone answer it . 
 For the group $G = \langle \mathbb{Z}_{12}, + \rangle$ and the subgroup $H = \{[0],[4],[8]\}$ of $G$, find all the left cosets of $H$ in $G$. Also obtain the corresponding coset decomposition of $G$.

Can anyone help me to solve this. may be with this above example i may understand the concept of coset.
Please

Comment: Let $G$ be a group. Let $H=\{\,h_1,h_2,\dots,h_r\,\}$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $g$ be in $G$. If we write the operation in $G$ as addition, then the coset of $H$ containing $g$ is $\{\,g+h_1,g+h_2,\dots,g+h_r\,\}$. Does that help?

Comment: {g+h1,g+h2,…,g+hr} are all left cosets ?

Comment: No, it is one left coset. (Or possibly one right coset – different textbooks use different definitions of left and right, when it comes to cosets.)

Comment: Ok thank you i understood how to write the cosets.. And for  right coset we write as Hg={h1+g,h2+g ....hr+g} ..is it right ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, let's try ( observe I omit all the cumbersome parentheses [.] )

$$H+3=\left\{0+3,\,4+3,\,8+3\right\}=\{ 3,\,7,\,11\}$$

Find the other ones (observe there are four **different** right cosets. Why?) ,and take into account that, for example:

$$H+11=H+3\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;11-3=8\in H\;\ldots$$

Comment: I understood.. But what Z suffix 12 indicates.. ?

Comment: If you don't know what ${\bf Z}_{12}$ means, Nani, then *that's* the first question you should be asking. But I find it hard to understand how it is that you don't have any materials explaining that notation to you.

Comment: @NaniBhavani Adding on Gerry's comment: the very least that is expected from someone asking something at mathematics in college/university level is that the asker know what the question talks about, and this means knowing what the symbols are (their definition), how operations (if any) are defined in algebraic structures being used, etc.

Comment: I am sorry.. I am very poor in this.. Still i dont know the symbol of Z12. what i am thinking is , it contains 0 to 12 elements in group Z . If its still wrong i am sorry. While i am posting the question i thought writing the left cosets from  0 to 12 elements of group Z. 
And till now what all i have learnt in group theory i didn't get this symbol any where. I just got (Z,*) thats it. so i am not sure about the new Symbolic form

Comment: I am expecting the answer ... Please.

Comment: @NaniBhavani Are you studying this somewhere or are you studying this alone, from some book or something?

Comment: Thank You so much.. I understood. From 0 to 12 we should write like a matrix form and based on that we write left and right cosets. I understood very well..Thank You for the valuable time.:)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the cosets of $H$ are things of the form $a+H$.

For instance:

- $0+H = \{0,4,8\}$
- $1+H = \{1,5,9\}$
- $2+H = \{2,6,10\}$
- $3+H = \{3,7,11\}$
- $4+H = \{4,8,0\}$
- $5+H = \{5,9,1\}$

etc.

Notice that at some point we start repeating, for instance:

$$0+H = 4+H, \qquad 1+H=5+H, \quad ...\mbox{etc.}$$

So the cosets of $H$ are

$$\{H,1+H,2+H,3+H\},$$

all of which are distinct.